# Gradle is failing in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

trunk: failed at 11/26/2019 9:50AM
Could not create parent directory for lock file C:\Program Files\gradle-5.6.4\wrapper\dists\gradle-5.6.3-bin\82hbcx3fecbatlnap0jtj8ysr\gradle-5.6.3-bin.zip.lck

Answer (score 0):

The folder `C:\Program Files` in Windows is by default protected and can only be changed if you do it with administrator rights. For the same reason, it is not supposed to be used as a work area for temporary or downloaded files. But this is what you are attempting to do.

When you run the Gradle wrapper scripts (through `gradlew`), it will download a Gradle distribution to your Gradle user home. The user home can be set by the environment variable `GRADLE_USER_HOME`, and if not set it will default to `$USER_HOME/.gradle`.

To me, it looks like you have downloaded a distribution manually (version 5.6.4) and then set `GRADLE_USER_HOME` to that folder. You shouldn't do that - just leave it to the default, or if you don't like that, another folder that doesn't require administrator rights to modify. Otherwise, Gradle will attempt to download the required distribution for your project (in your case version 5.6.3) to that folder and after that, create lock files and fill the cache with dependencies and more.

Some people also set a variable `GRADLE_HOME` to point to a default Gradle distribution. You can set this to the folder where you have manually downloaded it if you like, and then add `%GRADLE_HOME%\bin` to your `PATH`. But this is optional.

Comment: thanks for the  comment . we have done all the configuration already but today once i changed the Gradle location in new folder and setting also configure in intelij idea again . Its work fine. thank you !